# Why am I getting this error when creating a database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, project

```
# PHASE 1 (FILE I/O and Logic of System)
# Initialization of Current Balance ** Current Balance is the same for all users for the sake of simplicity ** 
myMoney = open("current_balance.txt")
currentBalance = int(myMoney.readline())

# Imports 
import sqlite3

# Creation of Bank Account and Notifying User(s) of Current Balance
class Bank_Account:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance= currentBalance
        print("Welcome to Your Bank Account System!")
    # If statements for first screen
    def options_1(self):
        ch = int(input("1. Create an Account\n2. Log into Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.create()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.Log_in()
    def options_2(self): 
        ch= int(input("1. Withdraw Money from Your Account\n2. Deposit Money to Your Account\nEnter a Choice: "))
        if ch == 1: 
            self.withdraw()
        if ch == 2: 
            self.deposit()
    # Function to Create an Account 
    def create(self): 
        user_create = str(input("Enter a Username:"))
        pin_create = int(input("Enter a Pin Number:" ))
        print("Account successfully created!")
     # Function to Log into Account 
    def Log_in(self):
        user = str(input("Enter your Username:"))
        pin = int(input("Enter your Pin Number:")) 
        print("Welcome", user, "!")
    # Function to Deposit Money 
    def deposit(self):
        amount=float(input("Enter the amount you want to deposit: "))
        self.balance += amount
        print("Amount Deposited: ",amount)
    # Function to Withdraw Money
    def withdraw(self):
        amount = float(input("Enter the amount you want to withdraw: "))
        if self.balance>=amount:
            self.balance-=amount
            print("You withdrew: ",amount)
        else:
            print("Insufficient balance ")

    def display(self):
        print("Net Available Balance=",self.balance)

# Creating an object of class
self = Bank_Account()
# Calling functions with that class
self.options_1()
self.options_2()
self.display()



# PHASE 2 (With Database) SQLite 3 

# Define Connection and Cursor 
connection = sqlite3.connect('Bank_Users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create Users Table 
command1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
bank(username TEXT PRIMARY KEY , pin INTEGER )"""
cursor.execute(command1)

# Add to Users/Bank
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES ('Kailas Kurup', 7620)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES ('Bethany Watkins', 4638)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES ('John Hammond', 3482)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES ('Melissa Rodriguez', 3493)")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO bank VALUES ('Gopalakrishnan Nair', 9891)")

# Get Results / Querying Database
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bank")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)

# Format Results 
print("username" + "\t\tpin")
print("-------" + "\t\t--------")
for result in results: 
    print(result[0] + " " + result[1] + "\t" + result[2])


# Phase 3 (With GUI) Tkinter
```

** I'm getting an

> Integrityerror: datatype mismatch error.

Why is this happening and what do I do to fix it? 'm trying to create a bank account management system where the user can create an account, log in, and withdraw/deposit money from that account. After completing the database portion of this project I plan on adding Tkinter GUI.***

Answer (score 0):

The program does NOT create the bank table (because it already exists) and the first column is not TEXT. PK  would care about datatype; not much else does. As a test, you could change the db connection in the program to `:memory:` to see if it works. Or look at the db with another tool, eg CLI, to see the `bank` table definition.

This is speculative, though not wild, because the problem can be reproduced with the described condition.